# Why does node.exe always run in background when I load Visual Studio 2013 solution?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013

VS2013 always starts node.exe when I load any Visual Studio 2013 solution. Regardless if I have any web projects or not it is always loaded.
Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Essentials 2013 Update 4 runs it for some reason

Probably because Web Essentials using open source Coffeescript and LESS parsers etc

Why it's running all the time must be a bug, because it loads for all project types, even if they have none of the Web Essentials target files!

Comment: If VS uses node as a javascript parser/console then it makes sense to run node all the time as a repl

Comment: @slebetman for a Winform app? You just have piles of c# code, nothing else. That makes no sense!

Comment: Thanks. Now I now its an extension not VS itself. Web essentials are a great tool and I will keep it even if it runs node.exe needlessly.